# How to get the values from this with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to learn beautifulsoup and is scraping this website.
My python code looks like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


print("Enter the last 3 characters from the share link")
share_link = input()
link = "https://website.com" + share_link
print(link)
r = requests.get(link)
raw = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(raw, features="html.parser")

print(soup.prettify)

inputTag = soup.find("input", {"id": "hiddenInput"})
output = inputTag["value"]

print(output)
```

It gives me this output:

```
{"broadcastId":"BroadcastID: 252940","rtmp_url":"rtmp://live.gchao.cn/live/23331_9wx2w0c9","sex":0,"accountType":"26073","hls_url":"http://live.gchao.cn/live/23331_9wx2w0c9.m3u8","onlineNum":99,"likeNum":67,"live_id":282878,"flv_url":"http://live.gchao.cn/live/23331_9wx2w0c9.flv?txSecret=40d318efbbbca6afb8be2450b8d1f8fa&txTime=5D6086D1","user_id":252940,"stream_id":"23331_9wx2w0c9","nick_name":"Princess","sdkAppID":"1400088004","info_id":33189,"info_name":"Hi","IM_ID":"@TGS#aXMZYZ7FB","earning":424}
```

How do I get inside this and with beautifulsoup get the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is json you can load with json library then parse e.g.

```
import json

s = '{"broadcastId":"BroadcastID: 252940","rtmp_url":"rtmp://live.gchao.cn/live/23331_9wx2w0c9","sex":0,"accountType":"26073","hls_url":"http://live.gchao.cn/live/23331_9wx2w0c9.m3u8","onlineNum":99,"likeNum":67,"live_id":282878,"flv_url":"http://live.gchao.cn/live/23331_9wx2w0c9.flv?txSecret=40d318efbbbca6afb8be2450b8d1f8fa&txTime=5D6086D1","user_id":252940,"stream_id":"23331_9wx2w0c9","nick_name":"Princess","sdkAppID":"1400088004","info_id":33189,"info_name":"Hi","IM_ID":"@TGS#aXMZYZ7FB","earning":424}'
data = json.loads(s)
print(data['broadcastId'])
```